# MySQL Replication binary relay logs transfer too slowly

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, master-slave-replication

#### Master server

MySQL 5.6.28

Ubuntu 14.04

8 core CPU

#### Slave server

Slave: MySQL 5.7.22

Ubuntu 18.04

16 core CPU

Both of them have 64GB of RAM and plenty of disk space.

#### What I did up to this point

I made a dump of the master database, copied it over to the slave server and set up a Slave database there. The replication works, but it's too slow.

The slave started approx. 2.5 days after the initial dump and isn't catching up. Looking at the relay log files, it seems that they're filling up too slowly (approx 1MB every few seconds). This is on a 100GB+ database.

#### I've tried

Checked the disk io with **iotop** - They're good on both the Master and the Slave. They're not SSDs but they don't seem to be the bottleneck.

Checked network speeds with **bmon** - they're barely scratching the surface. Both machines are on a Gigabit network. I've tried running `scp` (with the replication in progress) and I'm getting up to 100MB/s transfer. The relay logs seem to be transfering at less than 1MB/s.

Checked the **CPU** - both servers have plenty to spare.

I made sure the `innodb` settings are the same on both servers. All tables are `innodb`.

Looking at `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` I see that most of the time is spent waiting for new relay logs to transfer. There is no delay on the SQL side, it's always caught up.

Worth mentioning that the `binlog_format` is `ROW`.

#### tl;dr:

What could be limiting the speed at which the binlogs are relayed from Master to Slave, if there is still plenty bandwidth, CPU and disk I/O available?

**EDIT 1:**

Results of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`:

`Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: master.server
                  Master_User: sqlslave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.285479
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 87535361
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.001588
                Relay_Log_Pos: 87535479
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.285479
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 87535282
              Relay_Log_Space: 87535812
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 41260
                  Master_UUID: 2b9b59f9-4290-11e5-bf92-0cc47a02cb8e
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version:`

EDIT 2:

I'm leaning towards a combination of disk or network so I've been running `iostat` and `iotop`. The disk that gets the binlogs written to on the master is always near 100% utilization, but the "wait" is only about 10ms. Still, when I run `scp` it runs quickly, so I'm not sure why transferring the binlogs is about 200x slower.

There are also no errors on the Slave side, I'm monitoring the logs. Binlogs are disabled on the slave, and compressed binlogs are enabled.

Queries on the Slave are running fast, it's just that it keeps waiting on new relay logs to be transferred.

Comment: Please share the result of `show slave status` here.

Comment: Looks like your slave has already caught up. You said that it isn't catching up. Why do you think it isn't catching up? `Seconds_Behind_Master: 0`

Comment: @MontyPython `Seconds_Behind_Master: 0` is not a good metric in this case, because it is non-zero only when there's a new relay log file to process. They process quickly so most of the times it's 0, but when there's a file it's around 2.5 days.  Also, I can tell by comparing with `Show master status`, the log file there is `mysql-bin.285972` which a couple hundred files ahead.
Also I can tell by running `SELECT` queries on both, checking for the most recent row.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space on the slave? If not, MySQL might be retrying again and again to write the data to slave but won't be able to.

Comment: Yes, close to 1TB available. It's not failing, it's just writing really slowly. About 300kb/s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80859/discussion-between-montypython-and-nick-zinger).

Comment: Let's see `SHOW MASTER STATUS` _on the Master_ at about the same time as `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` _on the Slave_.  I want to compare the positions.  Also, are you configured to use GTIDs?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in my case the constraint was the Disk I/O. The binlogs are written to the hard disk which slows the whole thing down a bit.

The reason I couldn't see this at first was that MySQL was not using the Disk I/O to it's full potential, possibly due to settings or "niceness" of the MySQL process.

In the end it took a few days for the Slave to get caught up, and now it's fine. But potential, better solutions in the future:

- Write Binlogs to the SSD to reduce delays due to Disk I/O
- Try changing MySQL options such as `sysvar_innodb_io_capacity` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity
- Write to Hard Disk but ones in a RAID setup
- Increase the `nice` value for the mysql process to give it priority
- Switch to `STATEMENT` based binlog format, to reduce the binlog size.

One or many of the above might help fix similar issues.

Comment: On the Master, data does not go through the binlog to get to the slave; it is written to the network simultaneously with the disk writes.

Comment: Are you doing lots of multi-row `UPDATEs` and/or `DELETEs`?  In `ROW` mode, those can bloat the binlog (and relay log).

Comment: @RickJames Hmm, I am doing a lot of multi row updates/deletes, and the format is `ROW`. I felt it was safer, but I see what you mean. I'm going to have to revisit this - once I can. I used the replication to set up a server migration, and by now it's caught up (took 3 days for the Slave catch up). Will try with MIXED or STATEMENT next time.

Comment: MySQL started with only `STATEMENT`, and has been moving toward `ROW` as the "right" way to do replication.  I brought it up as a _possible_ way in which replication can be slower then the queries that are being replicated.  Yes, SSD and/or RAID _may_ be fixes.  But I prefer to get to the bottom of a problem, not simply "throw hardware at it".

Comment: I defaulted to `ROW` this time because last time I was using `STATEMENT` my slaves began to drift apart due to some poor queries. `ROW` is safer in my context(without fixing the code), but I totally forgot that that might help, so it's good to add as part of the answer - thanks!